# How can I run a gocd server on a Raspberry PI 4 running Raspbian Buster?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, go-cd

I'm trying to start up a gocd server using Docker on a Raspberry PI 4 running raspbian butler, and on start the initialization immediately fails with the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [this](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=gocd&type=image): The repo clearly said it just supports `x86-64`, so arm based raspberry-pi could not execute it, this is the reason you see your error.

Additional, what I suggest is you refer to `x86-64` gocd dockerfile [here](https://github.com/gocd/docker-gocd-server/blob/master/Dockerfile) to build your own image, of course you need to base on some [arm image](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=alpine%20arm&type=image), you had to be the first one and may feel pain when porting I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Found a gocd docker image that runs on arm-based processors: https://github.com/pellegrino/arm-gocd-server